# How to Centre Heading and Text Within a Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a panel within a column, within a row.

Inside of this panel I  have a heading, and some text within a paragraph.

I was wondering how I can centre these items within the panel that they are in?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code with us? Without it we cannot even begin to start assisting you.

Comment: Just added a sample, but it is pretty standard really, Praveen Kumar just answered it, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class `text-center` to the main `<div>`.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary text-center">
  <!-- -->
</div>
```

Whatever you put in `<p>`, `<table>`, inherit the `text-center` and have their text aligned center...

Comment: Thats brilliant, something so simple goes so far! Thank you!

Comment: I will, but I have to wait 9 more minuets, as the question has just been posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DIV class set up `div class="panel">` and you always want that text to be centered, then you can set up your CSS like:

```
div.panel {
 text-align: center }
```

If you only want this one div to have centered text (rather than an entire class) you could also try this in your html:

```
<div class="panel" align="center">
Content
</div>
```

This would only make this one `div.panel` centered rather than changing your css to make all `div.panel`'s centered.

Comment: Will this work on things other than text if done through CSS, like images etc?

Comment: I'm sorry I actually misspoke.  If you want it to align text or images, your css should look like how i updated my original post.

Comment: I tested it with a blank Dreamweaver document and it aligned anything in the `div.panel`, including items within a `<h2>`, `<p>`, and `<img>` tag.

Comment: Keep in mind that it will do this for any div that you make with that class, so if you have `<div class="panel">` divs that you don't want centered, this is probably not ideal.

Comment: Thats useful to know, if I don't it applied to everything though, I guess I can just give that div an id, and then use that in css instead. That way it will just apply to that one div.

Comment: Okay so I just edited my answer again.  I added an option where you can change it in just the html instead of changing you div class or creating a new class to center text.  This would just apply to the one particular div rather than all div's with that class.

Comment: @RageKage *Read this before you get downvotes*: **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#Attributes**, `The align attribute is obsolete; do not use it anymore.`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for the heads up.  I guess it's been awhile since I've done some coding - just pulled that bit from what I remembered from a couple of years ago.  :)

Comment: It's been at least that long since I've taken classes!  Haha.